# VB6 PictureBox Mouseover

Tags: vb6, user-interface, events, coding-style, mouse

I'm using a VB6 PictureBox on my User Control.  I set the PictureBox's picture, I set the BorderStyle to 0, and I set the BackColor to the User Control's BackColor.  The idea is that I want a "floating" icon.  However, I want that icon to appear clickable when the mouse hovers over it.

Two questions:

1. Which events do I use?  MouseMove seems to be the closest to a "MouseOver" event.  Are there any cleaner alternatives?
2. How should I change the style?  I've tried a few things, but none of them quite look right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. MouseMove is the correct event in VB6. You'll have to do some work to manually detect when the mouse leaves the client area cleanly. (My experiments in this world, lo those many years ago, always found implementing this behavior to be tricky.)
2. For changing the style, I'd recommend using GDI to: (a) shift the image one pixel up and to the left; (b) draw a single pixel line in the ButtonHighlightColor along the top and left edges; and (c) draw a single pixel line in the ButtonShadowColor along the bottom and right edges. This is trickier than it sounds, particularly in VB6, so ultimately I'd recommend ...

That you look at [vbAccelerator's toolbar controls](http://vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Controls/Toolbar/index.asp). They're free, and they'll probably get you most of where you want to be. (And yes, they're "classic" VB -- that is, VB6.)